# 'No space left on device' for a non-system partition

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, disk-usage, disk-management

I am using Xubuntu 16.04, it is installed on sda5. sda3 is a partition where I store my files. Xubuntu is complaining that there is no disk space for sda3. Simple operations such as copy/paste files does not work on sda3 (it does for sda5).

This problem arose after I ran the bash script from [here](http://blog.ovidiuparvu.com/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu-pc/).

I have two OSs installed. In Windows, I have the same problem as in Xubuntu, but with a different error msg: 'The volume is too fragmented to complete this operation'. So I analyze the disk in Windows but it shows 0% fragmented. Anyway, I know this is an Ubuntu forum, but hope this info helps. It seems that my disk is corrupted?

```
$ df -i
Filesystem        Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev              731523     557    730966    1% /dev
tmpfs             738993     783    738210    1% /run
/dev/sda5        5668864 1335766   4333098   24% /
tmpfs             738993      79    738914    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             738993       6    738987    1% /run/lock
tmpfs             738993      17    738976    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             738993      25    738968    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda3      234837616  361648 234475968    1% /media/HDD

$ df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             2926092         0   2926092   0% /dev
tmpfs             591196      8768    582428   2% /run
/dev/sda5       89082072  52819628  31714248  63% /
tmpfs            2955972      4224   2951748   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            2955972         0   2955972   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             591196        44    591152   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda3      763139688 528695288 234444400  70% /media/HDD
```

I tried to unmount my /tmp and got this error:

```
$ sudo umount /tmp
umount: /tmp: not mounted
```

I also did this:

```
$ sudo lsof / | grep deleted
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
snapd      846             root    6u   REG    8,5       4096 4980754 /tmp/selftest-squashfs-285157718 (deleted)
xfdesktop 2256            ali   16r   REG    8,5       4136 5393039 /home/ali/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
xfdesktop 2256            ali   17r   REG    8,5      32768 5393240 /home/ali/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-26d0afff.log (deleted)
upstart   2383            ali    9w   REG    8,5        205 5290292 /home/ali/.cache/upstart/indicator-sound.log.1 (deleted)
thunderbi 3601            ali   73r   REG    8,5       4136 5393039 /home/ali/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
thunderbi 3601            ali   78r   REG    8,5      32768 5393240 /home/ali/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-26d0afff.log (deleted)
chrome    3758            ali   29u   REG    8,5    8388608  394703 /home/ali/.config/google-chrome/BrowserMetrics/BrowserMetrics-5C7CFC13-EAE.pma (deleted)
```

I have also done apt autoremove and apt autoclean.

I have no idea what remains to be tried.

UPDATE:
I am using dual OS (Windows 7, Xubuntu 16.04) and I had the same problem (can't write to disk) in Windows as well. I ran the disk check in Windows which fixes the problem (free space marked as allocated in volume bitmap). My partition is NTFS if it matters.

Comment: If there's no space left on the device, remove something.  That's the only way you're going to be able to get more space.  As for the restarting of thunderbird, you're missing an `rd` at the end of thunderbird, and furthermore, what does this have to do with the question?

Comment: well, if you had read the question, there is space on the device, unless I am missing something which your comment didn't address. also, the process returned by lsof is 'thunderbi' not 'thunderbird'. I have also tried the latter, same error.

Comment: Okay, I *think* I'm starting to understand the confusion... your hard disk is split into several "partitions" or sections.  One of those sections is full, so you can't work on that partition until you've freed up some space (deleted some stuff) on it.  But again, what does restarting thunderbird and chrome have to do with your non-system partition being full?

Comment: I thought that deleted files which are hogged by processes might be taking up memory. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182077/best-way-to-free-disk-space-from-deleted-files-that-are-held-open  also, I have updated my qns. it turns out that in Windows, I can't copy/paste files as well.

Comment: I removed that part about restarting chrome and thunderbird. Those are not services, so you can't restart them as services so the commands you show are not relevant and are just distracting from your issue.

Comment: Does the problem persist after rebooting the machine? And can you please [edit] your question and show us the _exact_ output from a command that failed?

Comment: I have rebooted several times, it doesn't work. I can't show the exact output right now as I am running disk check in Windows as I suspect the hard disk might be damaged. The error is 'No space left on device' whenever I tried to write to the disk.

Comment: i have done that, the outputs are in the question. the inodes are not running out

Comment: I don't see any failed command and its output. Does something like `echo foo >  /media/HDD/testfile` work? Does it give the error? If so, please add this to your question (there are sometimes very similar error messages with slightly diferent causes, so it is important to show the _exact_ message and the command that caused it). Also, what filesystem do you have on `sda3`? Is it NTFS?

Comment: It is NTFS. I have resolved the problem. It turns out to be a non-Ubuntu error which somehow arose while I was running a bash scrip in Xubuntu. I will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am using dual OS (Windows 7, Xubuntu 16.04) and I had the same problem in Windows as well:

> The volume is too fragmented to complete this operation

Running disk defragmentation shows that the disk is 0% fragmented. I ran the [disk check](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/) in Windows which fixes the problem. The output from CHKDSK was:

> Free space verification is complete.
>
> Correcting errors in master file table's (MFT) BITMAP attribute.
>
> CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in volume bitmap.
>
> Windows has made corrections to the file system.

My partition is NTFS if it matters. Sorry that this fix is not done on Ubuntu. I just did whatever it takes to fix it.